# How to solve c3p0 concurrency issues?

Tags: java, mariadb, c3p0

I'm trying to implement database connection pooling. For some reason, I randomly get exceptions when I use multiple threads.

When I only have one, everything is fine. Also at least when I am testing, the issues appear only in the beginning. As I'm not sure what causes them, I can't really be sure they won't happen later on as well.

Using c3p0 version 0.9.5.2

`Example output from my test: https://pastebin.com/NrcR6mhz`

This test has 3 threads running simple query for 1000 times each. I cut the output shorter, as there are no exceptions later on.

Error messages for tl;dr version:

- You can't operate on a closed Statement!!!
- You can't operate on a closed Connection!!!

I won't bother uploading the whole project, as DB is configured separately. However, you can see the code of all of my classes here:

`Main - https://pastebin.com/1Rgjr8H5`

`Pool conf https://pastebin.com/wtbw1X5v`

`Controller https://pastebin.com/BvPh0guY`

As the c3p0 seems decent library imho, I would guess I'm doing something wrong here. Any tips please?

Comment: Please review: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve and http://idownvotedbecau.se/nocode/.  code goes in the question.  When you put your code, highlight the portion that gives the error (you did debug right?).  Links, even if input as text, are not good form on SO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, you need to think a bit about how multithreaded coding works, why one often should prefer objects accessible only in local scopes to instance or static member variables, and when one should synchronize for safe access of objects that must be shared between Threads.

Your most basic issue is the fact that `MariaController.connection` is a static member variable, when it should be entirely local to `isPlayerSuspended(...)`.

You also ought to mark the static `MariaConnectionPool.getInstance()` method `synchronized` [ which is equivalent to surrounding the body of the cod with `synchronized( MariaConnectionPool.class ){ ... }` ].

There may be other issues as well. Writing multithreaded code requires that you think carefully about what can be shared and when, and often the answer is to aoid sharing mutable state by working with it in objects accessible only via local references within methods (access to which is inherently single-threaded).

Comment: Thank you for the tips. Multithreading is new for me and I can often forget simplest things. Problem solved.